# Which analytics solution would you recommend?

Tags: analytics, metrics

I'm working on enhancing several applications at work, and thought of installing an analytics solution to track user behavior and collect some metrics. The problem is our company is a bit sensitive about privacy, and isn't comfortable with using Google Analytics.

So is there any other more private analytics solution I could use? and what do you use at your own company to track user behavior?

Comment: I don't think this is UX related, but more a question for SO. Anyway, you could roll out your own solution with an application server and copying the Google analytics script. Really not much too it.

Comment: In my experience, companies eventually change their policies and start using Google Analytics anyway, once someone high up in the companies actually sees Google Analytics.

Comment: How is GA *not* private(enough) for whoever's objecting? If they're worried about privacy, why were they/you looking at a hosted solution, anyway? It'd help to understand the question. And continuing from that are self-hosted packages an option?

Answer (score 2):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) specifically attempts to be an open-source self-hosted clone of Google Analytics.
If the base concern is privacy, the obvious thing to do is just remove any third parties.